# Error when adding an EF .edmx data model from SQL Compact Database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I've updated most all my projects to EF6, but have one that uses a SQL CE 4.0 database. I've updated the nUget packages, however now when I try and create an .edmx file I'm getting the following after it builds the classes: "Cannot load 'c:\users\dthompson\Documents\WindowsFormsApplication1\Model1.edmx': Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocaction.

This is then followed up with "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MarshalingWindowFrame'. It then takes me bakc to the Add New Item prompt. After this, the add data model wizard will simply disappear if I try to add it again. I've tried reinstalling the nuget packages and have tried Safe Mode. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to install the EF 6.1.2 Tools? Does your project target x64?

Comment: I have installed the 6.1.2 tools and my project was targeting x86. I fear I may have gummed up the nuget packages. I was using your SqlServerCompact.PrivateDeployment package. It would work fine until I deployed it on a client machine, then would throw an exception upon opening. I noticed the official EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact had been updated so I tried using it instead and now I can't get past these errors.

Comment: I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling all the packages. I thought it could be something with my project file so I've tried creating a new project using only your sqlce package but that doesn't work either.

Comment: What VS version/update? And target cpu?

Comment: VS 2012 (11.0.50727.1). Target CPU is 32bit. Thanks!

Comment: I am not able to repro, using the following: VS 2013 Update 4 (could be free community edition, EF 6.1.2 Tools, SQL Compact 4.0 SP1 MSI, and my EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.PrivateDeployment package (this is the only one you need to add to your project)

Comment: OK I've got it working in the test project I've created finally...so now it seems to be an issue with my main project, as I'm still getting those weird errors there. All I have installed is your package currently.

Comment: Compare .csproj files...